# How to move the location of a grid in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dijkstra's Path-Finding Algorithm Solver")
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

def title():
    button_font = pygame.font.Font('TrajanPro-Regular.otf', 40)
    rect_display = button_font.render('Dijkstra Path-Finding Algorithm', True, (255, 255, 255))
    # display global total deaths
    screen.blit(rect_display, (12, 10))

def title_underline():
    # create the button
    rect = pygame.Rect(0, 60, 800, 3)
    rect_display = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 255, 255], rect)
    button_font = pygame.font.Font('TrajanPro-Regular.otf', 100)
    rect_display = button_font.render('', True, (255, 255, 255))
    # display global total deaths
    screen.blit(rect_display, (270, 198))

def grid():
    blockSize = 20 #Set the size of the grid block
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*blockSize, y*blockSize, blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,200,200), rect, 1)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    title()
    title_underline()
    grid()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have created a title for my project and I created a grid for which I want to run my application, but the grid is being made in every single x, y location on my screen. But I want the grid to only be made under the title and not over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the top left coordinates of the grid (`grid_x`, `grid_y`) and add the coordinates when constructing the rectangle of a cell. For instance:

```py
def grid():

    grid_x = 12
    grid_y = 30
 
    blockSize = 20 #Set the size of the grid block
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            
            rect = pygame.Rect(
                grid_x + x*blockSize, grid_y + y*blockSize,
                blockSize, blockSize)
           
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,200,200), rect, 1)
```